# How to load a bitmap, with background color, into a TImageList in Delphi 5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-5, timagelist

### Short Version

Fill in the fuction:

```
procedure LoadImageListMasked(AImageList: TImageList; hbmp: HBITMAP; TransparentColor: TColor);
var
   bmp: Graphics.TBitmap;
begin
   bmp := Graphics.TBitmap.Create;
   bmp.Handle := hbmp;
   bmp.Transparent := True;
   bmp.TransparentMode := tmFixed;
   bmp.TransparentColor := TransparentColor;
   AImageList.AddMasked(bmp, TransparentColor);
   bmp.Free;
end;
```

### Long Version

I have a handle (`hbmp`) to a 256-color bitmap:

[image]

I want to load this image in a (Delphi 5) **TImageList**, using the `clFuchsia` as the mask color:

```
var
   bmp: TGraphics.TBitmap;

   bmp := TBitmap.Create;
   bmp.Transparent := True;           //Default: False
   bmp.TransparentMode  := tmFixed;   //Default: tmAuto
   bmp.TransparentColor := clFuchsia; //Default: $02FF00FF
   bmp.Handle := hbmp;

   ImageList1.Clear;
   ImageList1.Height := bmp.Height;
   ImageList1.Width := bmp.Height;
   ImageList1.BkColor := clNone;      //Default: $1FFFFFFF (clNone)
   ImageList1.AddMasked(bmp, clFuchsia);
```

Except when I actually *use* the images in the image list (on a **TToolbar** say), the `clFuchsia` color isn't masked off:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

### Options Grid

There are various options available to be played with:

- `bmp.TransparentMode`:  [`tmAuto`, `tmFixed`] (Default: `tmAuto`)
- `bmp.TransparentColor`: TColor (Default: -1)
- `bmp.Transparent`:      Boolean (Default: False)
- `ImageList1.BkColor`:   TColor (Default: `clNone`)

Lets try every combination i can think of:

| TransparentMode | TransparentColor | BkColor | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tmAuto (default) | -1 (default) | clFuchsia | Fail |
| tmAuto (default) | -1 (default) | clNone (default) | Fail |
| tmFixed | clFuchsia | clNone (default) | Fail |
| tmAuto (default) | -1 (default) | clNone (default) | then assign the handle: |
| tmAuto (default) | $02FF00FF (auto) | clNone (default) | Fail |
| tmAuto (default) | -1 (default) | clNone (default) | then assign the handle: |
| tmAuto (default) | $02FF00FF (auto) | clNone (default) | then change Mode to tmFixed: |
| tmFixed | $02FF00FF (auto) | clNone (default) | Fail |
| tmAuto (default) | -1 (default) | clNone (default) | then assign the handle: |
| tmAuto (default) | $02FF00FF (auto) | clNone (default) | then change mode to tmFixed: |
| tmFixed | $02FF00FF (auto) | clNone (default) | then change TransparentColor to clFuchsia: |
| tmFixed | $02FF00FF (clFuchsia) | clNone (default) | Fail |

After tracing through the VCL i realized there is another property of **TBitmap**:

```
TBitmap.Transparent: Boolean
```

It defaults to **False**. I've now also tried setting it to **True**.

Comment: Why are you using a compiler that is over 2 decades old? You should upgrade to a modern version.

Comment: We did pay for a newer version. It was so buggy and crashy that it went out of support while we were still fixing bugs. I've been trying Community Editions, waiting for a stable bug-free version that is worth spending any money on.

Comment: You say that your source image is 256 colored bitmap. But you don't specify color depth of your `ImageList` to be 256 of colors. If I'm not mistaken the default color depth for ImageList is 16 bit. Also the constant for `clFuchsia` is defined as 16 bit color depth. So passing that as parameter to `AddMasked` method might not work as expected.

Comment: Another thing you should consider is the fact that 256 colored bitmap also contains color palete that maps specific color value to those 256 colors that are to be used in the said bitmap. In fact it is possible to have color palete without `Fuschia` color being on it at all.

Comment: Have you perhaps considered using color of BottomLeft pixel of the source image to be treated as background color? This is what `TBitmap` and `TImageList` does in modern Delphi versions when no background or transparent color is being specified but transparency is still enabled. Not sure but perhaps Delphi 5 also does that. I recommend you check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set the `TImageList.BkColor`, leave it at its default of `clNone`.  You are telling the `TImageList` to draw its masked bitmaps onto the `TToolbar` over a fixed color.  That is why your `TToolBar` is showing fuchsia. It is the `TImageList.BkColor` being shown, not the `TBitmap.TransparentColor`.

---

Also, just as an FYI...

Don't set the `TBitmap.TransparentMode` property to `tmAuto` if you want a specific `TransparentColor`.

Setting the `TransparentColor` property to a value other than `clDefault` will set the `TransparentMode` property to `tmFixed`.  Then setting the `TransparentMode` back to `tmAuto` will set the `TransparentColor` back to `crDefault`, thus losing your color choice.

Though, it shouldn't really matter, as internally `AddMasked()` creates a new `TBitmap` copied from the source `TBitmap`, and it will set the copied bitmap's `TransparentColor` to the input `TColor` you specify, so you don't actually need to make your source `TBitmap` be transparent at all.

Comment: Updated the question to include your suggestions.